# Permissions while starting/stopping IIS website using powershell

Tags: powershell, iis, permissions

I have a WCF service that runs PS command to start IIS websites on the local machine as well as remote machines. The commands are:

```
$siteName = '" + siteName + "';
$serverName = '" + serverName + "';
$block = {" + block + "};
$session = New-PSSession -ComputerName $serverName
Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock $block -ArgumentList $siteName
```

To get this command to work, we need to add the application pool account running the WCF service to the administrators group on the machine where the website is hosted.

Is there a way this can be achieved without giving the application pool account admin access?

Regards,
Shilpa

Answer (score 2):

No, if you directly want to start an AppPool you have to be an admin.

A workaround is to have a Windows Service or frequently run scheduled task to start/stop the Application pool. Your site would just trigger this somehow. Dropping a file somewhere is easy to do and should work.

Answer (score 2):

Alright after some quick checking I found this,

> To use the Windows PowerShell cmdlets for IIS, you must be a member of the IIS Administrators or Administrators group, or you must have been delegated the appropriate authority.

This is from Misrosoft's website on the Admin tools for the Powershell CMDLETS, [Here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Ee790599.aspx)

So it looks like you can be a member of the IIS Admins and get the same ability.

UPDATE:

If you want others to be able to run Powershell you need to do the following;

```
Set-PSSessionConfiguration -Name Microsoft.PowerShell -showSecurityDescriptorUI
```

And confirm that you want to do the action, This brings up the following dialog box which allows you to give others the ability to run commands on that machine: 
[image]

I found this from [Microsoft](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2009/11/23/you-don-t-have-to-be-an-administrator-to-run-remote-powershell-commands.aspx) let me know if this fixes your issue.

Comment: Luke, thanks for the response. The user is an IIS administrator as described here --> http://blogs.technet.com/b/leesab/archive/2014/07/30/delegating-iis-administration-to-domain-users-non-administrators.aspx    However, the powershell command still isn't working remotely.

Comment: If you run it under your account (or Admin) does it work remotely?

Comment: Only if the account is a member of the server administrators group, it works remotely. If the account is a regular user account belonging to server Users, IIS_IUSRS, Network Access group, and is an IIS administrator, it does not work remotely.

Comment: Alright try this, I have updated my answer with code for you to try, let me know if it works/doesn't